# A word for a scrawny, ghastly but wise and academic or studious person

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, nouns

I'm looking for a word, not necessarily a direct “reverse dictionary” sort of word that has the definition above, but even a creative word that *can* describe, label, or represent that sort of person with just the one word. Having a slightly negative connotation is an added bonus, and a balance between negativity and positivity is also fine.

Again, the label sought is to describe, stand for, or attach to a wise and studious or academic person, but who is also frail and ghastly.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of "wizened" - but, despite the way it sounds, it doesn't imply wisdom, it just means "shriveled with age."

Comment: I think "nerd" captures a lot of it.

Comment: I love “wizened”, and for the reason you mentioned: it may not have a direct lexicographical link to the meaning above, but it combines the meaning [and] the “sound” of it. Please include it as an answer!

Comment: “Nerd” is the classic one, yes, but it is up to the sophistication I'm trying to represent; nerds are usually not associated with wisdom, and perhaps “ghastly” is taking it a bit too much to describe nerds. Hehe!

Comment: Do you mean "ghostly" by any chance?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I do mean ghastly, in the sense of being pale and sickly in a dreadful way.

Comment: A word doesn't necessarily exist just because you can describe some characteristics. Anyway, what is the point? Are you trying to write a ten-word book?

Comment: Are you the one who downvoted by any chance, Robusto? And regardless, a walking-blackhole-of-negativity much? Maybe I'm writing a fantasy with a certain caste that needs a name; considered that? Good Lord!

Comment: @Oldbag As I mentioned, you may want to include “wizened” as an answer. It may not denote wisdom & knowledge, but it connotes it, even if by the mere sound of the word. So far, it is my favorite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay... The word "***wizened***" means dried-up or shriveled with age. While the meaning does not include inferences to mystical knowledge - or even wisdom that comes with age - the *sound* of it may conjure those images, regardless.

Comment: As I commented elsewhere, I agree and truly love this word as a suggestion, then as an outright answer. Wizened does not denote wisdom & knowledge (in the definiens), but it connotes it, even if by the mere sound of the word; and by denoting withered, shriveled looks directly in the meaning or definition, I view it as the perfect word. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a single word.

Studious person = bookworm

**Names of actual creatures that attack books**

deathwatch beetle (larvae)

book-louse or paper-louse

**Words for ghastly people**

ghoul

scarecrow

gargoyle

**Suggestion**

I think a two-word phrase with alliteration might do it, e.g. "studious scarecrow"

I'm sure others can think of better ones.

Comment: Wizened wizard?

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, Chasly; it does help. Due to the needs of what I'm writing, I would prefer to stick to a one word. Open to what you mentioned about a two-word substantive with alliteration, but the chances of that “feeling” right are slim to the requirements of what I'm writing.

Comment: @ChrisH Oldbag above is the first one who suggested “wizened” and I actually love it. I explain in a comment above why, even if it does not denote the studious part besides the frailty, it still connotes it, even if the mere sound of the word.

Comment: @Rok I thought I'd take on the alliteration challenge in the answer using the suggestions in the comments.

Comment: @ChrisH Oh, that makes perfect sense! Yes, “wizened wizard” is indeed [the] perfect alliteration for the direct, almost exact meaning I was talking about. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a typical **necromancer** in fantasy fiction.

Comment: Necromancers may be stereotypically scrawny, ghastly and wise; but scrawny, ghastly and wise people are not typically necromancers.

Comment: @vladkornea Thank you! What sumelic said is very true; necromancer is not suitable for my specific need only because it will suggest involvement in rituals like reanimating the dead, etc. However, I wish I had rep of 15 to upvote your contribution, because I didn't think about it this way until you mentioned necromancer. I loved the feeling that I'm understanding what I'm talking about from a new perspective, so thank you!